# How to get user password before being encrypted outside the wordpress core once add a new user from dashboard?

Tags: password

I'm trying to match users' data in multiple wordpress applications, so when user created on one app the same user should be created on the other apps.
Here is the problem, I need to get the new created user plain password (outside of wordpress core) before being inserted on one of my apps so that I could insert this user data properly on the other apps.
Is there any action/filter or method to do so?

Comment: Even if this is possible, you should set up a single-sign-on system instead for all of the different apps to use for authentication e.g. using OpenID Connect or similar, not copy the password between systems

Comment: Assuming all sites use the same salt, you can just copy the hashed password to the other databases. A single sign-on solution would be far more reliable though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create users manually using `wp_create_user()` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

This would allow you to determine the password - but of course, you would have to be careful about how you share that with your other apps.

The other option is to share the public information ( email, username etc ) and then to return and update the password using `wp_set_password()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_password/

Answer (score 0):

Done by going through user_register action:

```
add_action('user_register', function($user_id) {
     //do what you need with $_POST['pass1']
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's right. Passwords are autogenerated by WordPress nowadays and emailed to the user, not supplied by the user on the registration form.